# Symfony Project: Parse Error in appDevDebugProjectContainer.php

Tags: php, symfony, nginx, compiler-errors, composer-php

I am setting up a Symfony project on a new iMac and I have been experiencing an issue, `Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ':', expecting ';' or '{' in /myproject/app/cache/dev/appDevDebugProjectContainer.php on line 20043`

I have looked into this error, and it seems that a few people believe it is related to the zend framework. I have tried changing the dependency version of zend, and checking all local dependencies but we are still experiencing issues. I have also run `brew update` and `brew upgrade`

I was wondering if anyone has any further suggestions of why this might be occuring?

Thank you!

Comment: What version of PHP and Symfony are you using?

Comment: what is there, in this line 20043?

Comment: Generally, this kind of error is solved after cleaning the cache. Try it.

Comment: Hi @fcpauldiaz, I am using PHP 7.0.8 and Symfony 2.8.

Comment: Hi @ChuckNorris. I have cleared the cache and not it mentions the following:
`Warning: Unsupported declare 'strict_types' in /project/vendor/ocramius/proxy-manager/src/ProxyManager/Configuration.php on line 19

Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ':', expecting ';' or '{' in /project/vendor/ocramius/proxy-manager/src/ProxyManager/Configuration.php on line 97`

I know which vendor this is referring to, but I think it must be a dependency to another module I have installed. There is another machine we have here that is working fine, and has done a composer update in past 12 hours.

Comment: Are you using the ocramius proxy manager ?

Comment: Hi @fcpauldiaz, Yes it seems a number of my dependencies: Zend, VichUploader Bundle and I believe Doctrine use this bundle.

Answer (score 1):

What you are seeing is a PHP parse error due to a return type being declared on a method, but the version of PHP you are using must not support return types, i.e, your web server is not using PHP 7.

I know you said you're running PHP 7.0.8, but that error seems to indicate otherwise (if Occam's razor is to be trusted). Remember that the PHP version being used by the web server may not be the same version that your shell PATH is finding at the command line.  If that is the case, then you need to update your .htaccess to inform the server to use the PHP 7 handler for PHP files. An example:

```
<FilesMatch \.php$>
SetHandler php70-cgi
</FilesMatch>
```

You would need to replace **php70-cgi** with whatever it needs to be for your server. If your installation is hosted on a third-party host, then ask them specifically what handler you should set.

I'm saying all this from experience: I found this thread and it helped me deduce that my problem was exactly this - I needed to update the .htaccess file to inform Apache which PHP handler to use, since my hosting company provides multiples, but the default was not PHP 7.

Answer (score 0):

I had a very similar problem when I updated to PHP 7. I found that there is BC in the ocramius proxy manager dependency. Use this version to fix the error: `"ocramius/proxy-manager": "^2.0.3"`